# Typeorm select max with specific column

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I want to select maximum value from a table's column named `quotationVersion` from table `quotation`,

### Code

```
  getOneMaximumQuotationVersion() {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder("quotation");
    query.select("MAX(quotation.quotationVersion)", "max");
    // query.addSelect("MAX(quotation.quotationVersion)", "max");
    return query.getOne();
  }
```

Comment: what issue are you facing with this query? Can you please post the actual question as to whats the issue with this?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add functions like **MAX**, **SUM** in the selection clause, you need to do **getRawOne()** or **getRawMany()**. This will give you the raw response:

```
getOneMaximumQuotationVersion() {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder("quotation");
    query.select("MAX(quotation.quotationVersion)", "max");
    // query.addSelect("MAX(quotation.quotationVersion)", "max");
    return query.getRawOne();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Methods `getOne` and `getMany` are used for selecting actual database entities. If you select a calculated value, you need to use `getRawOne` (or `getRawMany` for multiple values). Notice that the returned value is an object with the keys being the aliases you specified when calling `select`; in your case the alias is called `max`.

Also don't forget the asynchronous nature of the operation.

So, I'd rewrite your function like this:

```js
async getOneMaximumQuotationVersion() {
  const query = this.createQueryBuilder("quotation");
  query.select("MAX(quotation.quotationVersion)", "max");
  const result = await query.getRawOne();
  return result.max;
}
```

More information could be found in the [official documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/getting-values-using-querybuilder).

Comment: If anyone could explain what is wrong with this answer, I'd be very grateful. It still looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used this simple **repo pattern**:

```
const [maxValueEntity] = await this.repo.find({
    order: {
        value: 'DESC',
    },
    take: 1,
});
```

For more complex cases, you can play with the following cases:

1\ query result:

```
const maxValueQuery = this.createQueryBuilder('entity')
    .select('MAX(entity.value)')
    .getQuery();
```

2\ entity result:

```
const maxValueEntity = await this.createQueryBuilder('entity')
    .where(`entity.value = (${maxValueQuery})`)
    .getOne();
```

3\ raw result:

```
const maxValueRaw = await this.createQueryBuilder('entity')
    .select('MAX(enity.value)', 'max')
    .getRawOne<{ max: string }>();
```

> More typeorm subquery test cases [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/query-builder/subquery/query-builder-subquery.ts)

Answer (score 1):

If you have come here finding out how to give min, max value to column in typeorm then this is the way to do it

```
@Column()
@IsInt()
@Min(0)
@Max(10)
rating: number;
```

For further details, [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/validation)