# Get minimum column value from related entity

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Please, help me. I cant find information about how do this.
I have got this code. It load all products with all relations. One of relations is product item. In product item entity I have got price column.

How I can get minimal product item price without get in my response array of product items?

```
const { skip, take } = pagination;

    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('product');

    query.where('product.shop = :id AND product.blocked = FALSE', {
      id: shop.id,
    });

    if (skip) {
      query.offset(Number(skip));
    }

    if (take) {
      query.limit(Number(take));
    }

    query.leftJoin('product.info', 'info');
    query.leftJoin('product.avatar', 'avatar');

    // load product items
    query.leftJoin('product.productItem', 'item');

    query.select([
      'product.id',
      'product.path',
      'info.name',
      'info.description',
      'info.info',
      'info.lang',
      'avatar.path',
      'avatar.type',

      'item.price'
    ]);

    const [list, amount] = await query.getManyAndCount();
```

Now i have got:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "path": "admin-product-2",
            "order": 1,
            "shop": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "Admin Name ;)",
                    "description": "Shorty",
                    "info": "",
                    "lang": "RU"
                }
            ],
            "avatar": null,
            "productItem": [
                {
                    "price": 1000
                },
                {
                    "price": 500
                },
                {
                    "price": 300
                },
                {
                    "price": 2000
                },
                {
                    "price": 3000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
........
```

But I need:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "path": "admin-product-2",
            "order": 1,
            "shop": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "Admin Name ;)",
                    "description": "Shorty",
                    "info": "",
                    "lang": "RU"
                }
            ],
            "avatar": null,
            "minProductItemPrice": 300
        }
    ]
}
```

Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for this on Stackoverflow already.

Here is a similar question [Typeorm select max with specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250232/typeorm-select-max-with-specific-column)

Basically, `getManyAndCount()` method that you are using is useful when fetching entities. In your case, you are trying to obtain an aggregate value encompassing multiple entities.

You need to make separate selection, like so

```
query.select("MIN(item.price)", "min");
```

and then get the result with

```
return query.getRawOne();
```

Comment: Specifically with getMany() ? No, I don't think so.
But you can get raw data with many using getRawMany().
Have a read here 
https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/getting-values-using-querybuilder